# Why the app is removed from the Build section in testflight after it is uploaded

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have not yet registered the app in the App Store...
When the upload is successful with xcode, it enters the builds section in testflight for a few minutes, but then it deletes itself and leaves no message.
What is the problem?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score -3):

This solve my problem.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to access your camera to capture a photo add and update profile picture.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to access your photo library to select a photo add and update profile picture</string>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it